# SelectListItem in Selected Property doesnt work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**Controller**

```
Kullanicilar kullanici = db.Kullanicilar.Where(f => f.Id == 
   userProfileModel.UserModel.Kullanici.UserID).FirstOrDefault();

foreach (var item in db.Tanimlar.Where(f => f.TanimTipId == (int)ETanimTip.Kategoriler))
userProfileModel.AvaliableCategories.Add(item: new SelectListItem() 
{ 
    Text = item.Kod, 
    Value = item.Id.ToString(), 
    Selected = item.Id == kullanici.CategoryId 
});
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.CategoryId, Model.AvaliableCategories, 
  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "AvaliableCategories"  })
```

When i was a look at selected value, i see true but view result is false..
[true value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U9Ut.png)
[false result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1zoB.png)
What do i now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AvaliableCategories)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.Value" selected="selected">@item.Text</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                    }
                }
```